# I Want to use this Text on My App. I need a hand with it

Tags: ios, dictation

My English is Very Poor.
I created an Applewatch app Wich the IPhone version of this app has nothing to show. so i want to put a funny text on there.

1- is this text gona make apple reject my app?
2- please help me manage this text and fix the dictations problems and etc...

thanks in advance.

here is the text:

hello
All The Staff is on the Apple Watch app. 
so You can hide This app Somewhere...
However I Placed a Switch Button So You can Play With...
This Button is not Doing Anything, But Rumors say if You Switch it 1000 time, You will Rewarded with an Apple Watch Gold Edition.
But Don't Trust this. Its just a Rumor...

Comment: Please tell me what you mean with the 1st sentence, b/c it does not make any sense to me as it is right now.

Comment: because this text is no related with app and its just for fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Apple is not going to reject anything for typos or grammatical errors.

2: Here you go:

> Hello, all staff members are shown in the Apple Watch App which allows you to hide the app somewhere. However, I placed a switch in the app you can play with. It does not do anything but rumor has it, if you switch it a 1000 times, you will be rewarded an Apple Watch Gold Edition. Don't believe it, it's just a rumor.

Comment: i think the meaning of my text is different with your text! can you make it more fun please?